# Explain the information given in the routing table for an Android device?

Tags: android, networking, routes

This is what the routing table looks like

```
Iface   Destination     Gateway         Flags   RefCnt  Use     Metric  Mask            MTU     Window  IRTT

wlan0   00000000        0101A8C0        0003    0       0       0       00000000        0       0       0

wlan0   0001A8C0        00000000        0001    0       0       312     00FFFFFF        0       0       0

wlan0   0101A8C0        00000000        0005    0       0       0       FFFFFFFF        0       0       0
```

What do the numbers under *Destination* and *Gateway* mean? For that matter, I'd like to know what the values under the other columns mean too.

Also, my device is connected only to a wireless network, in the routing table it shows wlan0 three times. Why does that happen?

Answer (score 0):

First of all i'am not an android expert. I would interpret these values as hexadecimal values.
You have three entries, because your network interface knows 3 networks in which it can send data.
For example entry 1:
The destination is 00000000 in decimal it would be 0.0.0.0. It's the entry for the internet. When you send something to the internet, the data will be send via a gateway. Which has the adress 0101A8C0 that's 192.168.1.1 this address is probably your router interface.
Flags gives you details about the route, for example if it's learned dynamically.
Use value represented the number of lookups for this route.
Metric is the distance to the target. It is usually the amount of devices to the target. 
Mask is the subnetmask of the destination. MTU describes the max size of the packet. 
Window is the value for Default window size for TCP connections over this route.
Initial RTT (Round Trip Time). The kernel uses this to guess about the best TCP protocol parameters without waiting on (possibly slow) answers.